# Xdebug is not launched in WSL2 in a docker CakePHP 3 application

Tags: xdebug, cakephp3

I am struggling with **Xdebug + WSL2 + CakePHP 3 + VSCode**. Checking the debug console it seems that I have running Xdebug correctly, but when I run a script in the browser, the Xdebug is not launched. This is the code:

**Note**: I forgot to mention that I am working on docker, that's why the "0.0.0.0" in the hostname parameter.

This is the **xdebug.ini**

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host='host.docker.internal'
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms=2000
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
  
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/webroot": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the debug console:

```
Listening on { address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 9003 }
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}

<- initializedEvent
InitializedEvent { seq: 0, type: 'event', event: 'initialized' }

-> setBreakpointsRequest
{
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  arguments: {
    source: {
      name: 'index.php',
      path: '/root/server/webroot/index.php'
    },
    lines: [ 40 ],
    breakpoints: [ { line: 40 } ],
    sourceModified: false
  },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 3
}

<- setBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 3,
  command: 'setBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: {
    breakpoints: [
      {
        verified: true,
        line: 40,
        source: {
          name: 'index.php',
          path: '/root/server/webroot/index.php'
        },
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

The xdebug.log file

```
[20] Log opened at 2022-05-16 04:42:03.776649
[20] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[20] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[20] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/webroot/info.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.19" protocol_version="1.0" appid="20"><engine version="3.1.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[20] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[20] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>



[20] [Step Debug] <- run -i 12
[20] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="12" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[20] [Step Debug] <- stop -i 13
[20] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="13" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

[20] Log closed at 2022-05-16 04:42:03.812679
```

**UPDATE**: Following this suggestion (I got from this link, by HolyGonzo) https://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/rqiw4h/need_help_troubleshooting_xdebug_configuration/ I added **xdebug_break()**; to my code, and then the debugger started working. It is pretty clear to understand that the issue it is in the VSCode configuration not in Xdebug.

Comment: How do you trigger the debugging request?

Comment: Well, I just click on VSC in "Listen for Xdebug". The Debug console returns success: true, that's why I think the Xdebug is running, but maybe something in my config is wrong.

Comment: @R0bertinski 1) No need to have the same config lines written twice: it will not make it more important or have more value  2) Show your `xdebug_info()` output captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (a web page or a CLI script) -- that's to see the actual live parameters.

Comment: @LazyOne I am sorry I don't know what you means with " No need to have the same config lines written twice" It was not my intention and I did not write it twice.  Anyway thanks about  xdebug_info() I never use it before. It outputs lot of information, I will try to update the post to add it. Thanks.

Comment: I've realized thanks to this output, that xdebug is reading a different .ini, I will update the path in my Docker file and will see. Thanks

Comment: @R0bertinski *"I am sorry I don't know what you means with " No need to have the same config lines written twice""* Your xdebug.ini content -- you have some lines written more than once: `zend_extension=xdebug` and `xdebug.start_with_request=yes`

Comment: @R0bertinski *"I've realized thanks to this output, that xdebug is reading a different .ini"* It's not Xdebug that reads the INI file. It's PHP itself. *"I will update the path in my Docker file and will see. Thanks"* Please do and write about your results here.

Comment: Update: I fixed the xdebug logs permission issues but still not working, not idea what more I can do. Thanks

Comment: Ok, yeah it was duplicated, but I already updated and still not working, I did not see before :), thanks.  And yeah you right, it is php not xdebug as you said.

Comment: So you need to show your xdebug log for such debug session (as well as full current output of `xdebug_info()`). It may give some hints. In either case -- check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw

Comment: @LazyOne I've updated the post with the debug console information.

Comment: @LazyOne I've added the xdebug.log as well. Everything looks good to me, but the debugger steps arrows are not activated in the VSC. Thanks

Comment: I tried to change the port (just in case) following this steps one by one, but still not working. https://gist.github.com/antfroger/1f2b24fdba0f215a41c8a94e8aa062f7

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**
After fight with this thing a few days, finally I found the issue:
In the **launch.json** in VSCode I updated this line and it works!!! (note that my path was wrong :( I had this "/var/www/webroot" instead of "/var/www/html/webroot").

```
   "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/webroot": "${workspaceFolder}/webroot"
            },
```

**Update**:
In order to allows Xdebug to look into the vendors folder, and the other folders outside /webroot, the code needs to be upated as follows (in my case, regarding to my server paths):

```
 {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 5902,
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "log": true
        }
```